# {be} viewed as + ing-word

Tags: idioms

Is the expression "viewed as marking" considered idiomatic? I was wondering this because in the following SAT problem, the answer is no error.

> Jean Toomer was not only the author of Cane, a novel whose publication has been viewed as marking the beginning of the Harlem Renaissance, but also a respected advisor among Quakers.  No error

However, it seems quite strange because I have not heard it being used much. Could someone give more examples of similar cases in addition to the first question?

Comment: _Be regarded as_, _be seen as_, _be viewed as_ may all be followed by _ing_- words (often as part of a 'present participial phrase'). 'He is regarded as having enough money to build a new Titanic.'

Comment: Right. _`A` is regarded/seen/viewed as `VP` comes via passives from _`Indef` regards/sees/views `A` as `VP`_. So "viewed as marking" isn't really a constituent; it's just a few words strung together in a particular construction.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think "marking" is part of *present participial phrase*. It is just a gerund used as an object of *a preposition*, as.

Comment: @Rathony I'm never happy with the terminology hereabouts. The inverted commas in my comment are scare quotes. I nearly used 'string headed by an _ing_-word'. But I'd say that 'marking' here is nearer the verb end of the continuum than the noun end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simplify the core clause with which you have a problem and try to change it from the passive voice to the active voice as it is easier to understand.

> whose publication has been viewed as marking the beginning of the
>   Harlem Renaissance

can be changed to

> People have viewed (**considered/regarded/understood/looked upon/thought of, etc**)
>   the publication **as** *marking the beginning* of the Harlem Renaissance.

We view a lot of things [*as*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) as things that have a different capacity, role, character, condition, etc. That's why "as" was used as a preposition to represent things that are *viewed/understood/considered/regarded/looked upon/thought of* in different **capacity, role, character, condition, etc.**

"marking" in the sentence is not something that leads a present participial pharase. It is a [**gerund**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gerund) that is used as an object of a preposition, "**as**". In the setnence, you can change "*marking*" into "**something that marked the beginning of the Harlem Renaissance**".

You have to change a verb into a gerund to use as an object of a preposition.

Comment: 'People have considered the publication to mark the beginning of the Harlem Renaissance' is a paraphrase and brings out the (in my opinion) intrinsic more verbal flavour of 'mark...' here. // However we analyse it, it's acceptable!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you *view/consider" A as B, B is something else in capacity, role, character, condition etc. Noun can be always omitted as it is redundant. I view/consider him as smart. This sentence is a shortened form of "I view him as a smart guy." The above sentence should have been constructed as "people have viewed the publication as a publication (something) that has marked the... "marking" alone means something that has marked... and that's why I believe it has more noun flavour than verbal. I absolutely agree with you on "however" part.

Comment: Quirk et al have an analysis of the noun-verb continuum of _ing_-forms in ACGEL. I prefer their analysis to that of CGEL.